# Laravel database raw concat replace

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a problem, below my code

```
$data = client_conf::select('cont_id','default_cont_id')->where('client_id',$client_id)->first();
$cont_id = explode(',', $data->cont_id);
$res_ = "'".implode("','", $cont_id)."'";

$custom2 = DB::table('client_conf as a')->where('client_id',$client_id)
    ->select(DB::raw("
        a.cont_id as id_list,
        a.default_cont_id id_default,
        (SELECT bank_fee_trans_inter FROM payout_cont as t WHERE t.cont_id=a.default_cont_id) as fee_trans_inter,
        (SELECT bank_fee_skn FROM payout_cont as t WHERE t.cont_id=a.default_cont_id) as fee_skn,
        (SELECT bank_fee_skn FROM payout_cont as t WHERE t.cont_id=a.default_cont_id) as fee_rtgs,
        (SELECT bank_fee_trans FROM payout_cont as t WHERE t.cont_id in ($res_) and t.bank_cd='$bank_cd') as fee_trans_same,
        (SELECT cont_id FROM payout_cont as t WHERE t.cont_id in ($res_) and t.bank_cd='$bank_cd') as id_trans
    "))
    ->first();
```

the result $cont_id is = AAA,BBB

anyone can help to simplified the query ?
so I can do once queries, didnt need do twice. (first queries to get cont_id then I'm implode it first, then do the second queries).

the problem is $res_

I'm already trying using concat and replace,

example try : `concat('\'',replace(a.cont_id,',',"','"),'\'')`. but get result id_trans = null.

if anyone can help to resolve it, I'm very thanksfull.

last `->first()` change to `->tosql()`

```
SELECT a.cont_id AS id_list, a.default_cont_id id_default, 
       (SELECT bank_fee_trans_inter 
        FROM   payout_cont AS t 
        WHERE  t.cont_id = a.default_cont_id) AS fee_trans_inter, 
       (SELECT bank_fee_skn 
        FROM   payout_cont AS t 
        WHERE  t.cont_id = a.default_cont_id) AS fee_skn, 
       (SELECT bank_fee_skn 
        FROM   payout_cont AS t 
        WHERE  t.cont_id = a.default_cont_id) AS fee_rtgs, 
       (SELECT bank_fee_trans 
        FROM   payout_cont AS t 
        WHERE  t.cont_id IN ( 'AAAA', 'BBB' ) 
               AND t.bank_cd = 'CENA')        AS fee_trans_same, 
       (SELECT cont_id 
        FROM   payout_cont AS t 
        WHERE  t.cont_id IN ( 'AAAA', 'BBB' ) 
               AND t.bank_cd = 'CENA')        AS id_trans 
FROM   `client_conf` AS `a` 
WHERE  `client_id` = ?
```

I'm already find the solution using find_in_set.
below my update code

```
$custom2 = DB::table('client_conf as a')->where('client_id',$client_id)
            ->select(DB::raw("
                a.cont_id as id_list,
                a.default_cont_id id_default,
                (SELECT bank_fee_trans_inter FROM payout_cont as t WHERE t.cont_id=a.default_cont_id) as fee_trans_inter,
                (SELECT bank_fee_skn FROM payout_cont as t WHERE t.cont_id=a.default_cont_id) as fee_skn,
                (SELECT bank_fee_rtgs FROM payout_cont as t WHERE t.cont_id=a.default_cont_id) as fee_rtgs,
                (SELECT bank_fee_trans FROM payout_cont t,client_conf j WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t.cont_id,id_list) <> 0 and t.bank_cd='$bank_cd' group by t.bank_fee_trans) as fee_trans_same,
                (SELECT t.cont_id FROM payout_cont t,client_conf j WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t.cont_id,id_list) <> 0 and t.bank_cd='$bank_cd' group by t.cont_id) as id_trans
            "))
            ->first();
```

Comment: Please replace the last `->first()` with `->toSql()` and post the result.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir , kindly check it

Comment: is it correct ? please help @JonasStaudenmeir